# How To Get Mulitple ID related value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My first table name is user, this table contain products like by user

user

```
id username products
1  abc       2,3,4
2  cde       1,2
```

another table products contain related products list

```
id products
1   pro1
2   pro2
3   pro3
4   pro4
```

Now i want show user contained products, but not show products id. output like,

```
abc pro2,pro3,pro4
```

Comment: Please don't store CSV in your SQL tables.

Comment: You should not store comma seperated values in one column Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT  u.username,
GROUP_CONCAT(p.products ORDER BY p.id) products_list
FROM    users u
INNER JOIN products p
ON FIND_IN_SET(p.id, u.products) > 0
GROUP   BY u.id;

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ce236/2)